# laravel 5.7 how to pass variable id of one controller to other

Tags: php, laravel

I have two controllers and I try pass id of variable form method   one controller to method to second controller   and I got an error like this >MethodNotAllowedHttpException  . I will add that my url after the action looks like this >http://localhost/comment?12   . How is the best way of solving this problem ?

Comment: please add code of your controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most probably getting `MethodNotAllowedException`, because you are opening a route that is defined as a `POST` route via `GET` or the other way around.

To avoid that you can use `php artisan route:list` and get a list of all defined routes and see how you should "access" them:

```
+--------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                                                | Name                   | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /a/show/{id}                                       |                        | App\Http\Controllers\AController@show                                  | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | /b/show/{id}                                       |                        | App\Http\Controllers\BController@show                                  | web          |
```

So let's say you have 2 controllers: `AController` and `BController`. Each of the controllers have a `show()` method declared in them.

```php
class AController extends Controller {

    //... other AController related code

    public function show($id) {
        dd($id);
    }
}


class BController extends Controller  {

    //... other BController related code

    public function show($id) {
        dd($id);
    }

}
```

Then you can define your routes like this:

```
Route::get('/a/show/{id}', 'AController@show');
```

Links like: example.com`/a/show/10` will "load" `AController`'s `show()` method. All we have in our `AController::show()` method's body is [dump and die](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-dd) on `$id`, we will get *10* printed if we visit that link.

We can replace that `dd($id);` with:

```
redirect()->action('BController@show', ['id' => $id]);
```

And define another route:

```
Route::get('/b/show/{id}', 'BController@show');
```

This way if we open the previous link: example.com/a/show/10, we will be redirected to: example.com`/b/show/10` and `BController::show()` method will be executed and it prints the variable using [dump and die](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-dd).

Key points:

- [Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-parameters)
- [Controller Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#basic-controllers)
- [`redirect()`-ing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redirects#redirecting-controller-actions)